# I am the purpose of this riddle

Tags: riddle

I am the purpose of this riddle
and I am without grace.
I dislike comfort,
but give me the title of doctor,
and I'll go back and forth in an eternal loop for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Awkward

I am the purpose of this riddle

> self fulfilling line I suppose

and I am without grace.

> definitely awkward

I dislike comfort,

> definitely awkward

but give me the title of doctor,

and I'll go back and forth in an eternal loop for you.

> Dr awkward is a palindrome

Answer (score 10):

Answer:

> "Who"

Note: the explanation is slightly out of order but it all ties together.

I am the purpose of this riddle:

> This could be a "who am I" riddle.

but give me the title of doctor,
and I'll go back and forth in an eternal loop for you.:

> Doctor who is a time lord who travels back and forth through time and space solving problems for "you" being the average person who doesn't know what's happening.

I dislike comfort:

> Doctor Who travels in a Tardis - doesn't seem very comfortable to me, even if it's big on the inside.

I am without grace:

> The Tardis is old and unreliable - hardly graceful, in any case. Furthermore, Doctor who is fairly eccentric - as defined on the internet:  eccentricity (also called quirkiness) refers to unusual or odd behavior on the part of an individual. This is also usually not graceful.

Comment: Cool answer! There is an answer that fits the clues better though. +1